# ko.mapping.fromJS(rawJSON) resulted in a undefined object

Tags: knockout.js

What is the best way to find out why this resulted in a undefined viewModel, after the ko.mapping.fromJS line?

The rawJSON looks fine in the chrome js object explorer

```
    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(rawJSON);
        viewModel = decorateViewModel(viewModel);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

view in chrome:

```
rawJSON: Object
   Companies: Array[1]
   CompaniesFollowing: Array[0]
   DisplayName: null
   DateCreated: "2013-03-11T21:50:21.9"
   __proto__: Object
viewModel: undefined



  function decorateViewModel(viewModel){
            viewModel.CompaniesFollowing().forEach(function(self) {
                self.isFollowing = ko.observable(true);
                self.toggleIsFollowing = function () {
                    if(self.isFollowing()){
                        unFollowCompany()}
                    else{
                        followCompany();
                    }
                    self.isFollowing(!self.isFollowing());//reverse it so the user can see the button text change
                };
                self.followButtonText = ko.computed(function () {
                    return self.isFollowing() ? "Unfollow" : "Follow";
                });
                self.styleClass = ko.computed(function () {
                    return self.isFollowing() ? "radius button" : "radius secondary button";
                });
            });
```

the rawJSON:

```
  var rawJSON = { "Companies" : [ { "DateCreated" : "2013-03-11T21:53:31.123",
     "Description" : "eee",
     "EquityOffered" : 3.0,
     "FollowingUsers" : null,
     "Id" : 1,
     "InvestmentFound" : 0.0,
     "InvestmentSought" : 3333.0,
     "LogoFileName" : "4ED564E6-CDBB-4045-8E55-9581B7FA13E0.jpg",
     "Name" : "Model Adapt",
     "SocialDetails" : null
   } ],
  "CompaniesFollowing" : [  ],
  "DateCreated" : "2013-03-11T21:50:21.9",
  "DateUpdated" : "2013-03-11T21:50:21.9",
  "DisplayName" : null,
  "FullName" : null,
  "HomeAddress" : null,
  "Id" : 1,
  "Investor" : { "AvailableFunds" : 0.0,
      "DateCreated" : "2013-03-11T22:30:07.273",
      "DateUpdated" : "2013-03-11T22:30:07.273",
      "Description" : "kbibkb",
      "FollowingUsers" : [  ],
      "Id" : 1,
      "Interests" : "bukb",
      "LogoFileName" : null,
      "Name" : "giu",
      "Skills" : "kbku",
      "SocialDetails" : null
    },
  "InvestorsFollowing" : [ { "AvailableFunds" : 0.0,
        "DateCreated" : "2013-03-11T22:30:07.273",
        "DateUpdated" : "2013-03-11T22:30:07.273",
        "Description" : "kbibkb",
        "FollowingUsers" : [  ],
        "Id" : 1,
        "Interests" : "bukb",
        "LogoFileName" : null,
        "Name" : "giu",
        "Skills" : "kbku",
        "SocialDetails" : null
      } ],
  "LogoFileName" : null,
  "MiniAbout" : null,
  "UserName" : "Master_"
}
```

Comment: What does `decorateViewModel` do? Can you put up a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) replicating the result?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker  see my edit :) note its undefined before I decorate it

Comment: I assume `rawJSON` is a JavaScript object, not a JSON string. If it's a JSON string, you should be using `ko.mapping.fromJSON`, but I assume that's not your issue.

Comment: @EvanHahn its a js object :)

Comment: Can you actually post the raw JSON, rather than Chrome's interpretation of it? You can get it from the network tab of the dev tools, I think. Ot use Fiddler to capture the traffic.

Comment: @PaulManzotti np, I've stuck it in the edit:) thanks for nay light you can shine on it!

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker how do I add knockout.mapping-latest.js to fiddle?

Comment: @FutuToad Add a resource and enter //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.3.5/knockout.mapping.js as the address.

Comment: @PaulManzotti why is fiddle so fussy about external files needing this cdnjs stuff?

Comment: It's actually github that is the issue here, it doesn't serve JavaScript files with the correct mime type, so the browser can't cope with it. I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it definitely `var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(rawJSON);` that is resulting in viewmodel being null, or is it `viewModel = decorateViewModel(viewModel);`, because iy would appear that your decorateViewModel method is not returning the view model, which would result in it being null after that line has been processed.

Comment: oh.. I don't believe this, the mapping worked!! it was my decorate thing that failed.. too much programming last night I'm afraid!

Comment: I do admit that getting up to speed with functional programming is a rough ride but its worth the perseverance.

Comment: all I had to do was     return viewModel; in the decorator.. do you think this is a good way to do things? it sure is handy

Comment: I would personally be looking to do it all with the mapping plugin. Look up the create method on the mapping documentation page (sorry, on my phone atm, can't get the link for you)